# Adding a new class to DSpace 4.2 xmlui

Tags: ant, dspace, apache-cocoon

I want to add a new java class to DSpace. I've followed this [link](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Manakin+theme+tutorial#Manakinthemetutorial-Addingstaticpages) for adding a static page. I made all the necessary changes. After rebuilding the package and running ant update, I'm still not being able to see any change. 
I checked my dspace installation directory, and found that the class added by me in not there in it.
It would be very helpful if I find a tutorial which explains step by step how to incorporate a new java class in DSpace 4.2. Could someone help me out or share some useful links. Thanks in advance.

I used the cocoon based method.These are the steps which I followed:

1. I created a java file TestPage.java in `[dspace-src]/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/discovery/`.
2. Then I made changes to the sitemap as specified in the instructions in the link in `[dspace-src]/dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/Discovery`.

I added this under `<map:transformers>`

```
<map:transformer name="TestPage" src="org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.discovery.TestPage" />
```

This was added under `<map:pipelines>
        <map:pipeline>`

```
<map:match pattern="test">
  <map:transform type="TestPage"/>
  <map:serialize type="xml" />
</map:match>
```

And finally I changed `page-structure.xsl` to include a link to the new page which I created, within `<xsl:template match="dri:body">`

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='contextPath'][not(@qualifier)]"/>
        <xsl:text>/test</xsl:text>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <i18n:text>Test</i18n:text>
</a><br/>
```

Comment: You will need to give a little bit more detail I'm afraid -- what changes did you make? Where did you put your class? Are you pulling it in via the sitemap as explained in the instructions you're linking to?

Comment: I thing <map:transform type="TestPage"/> should be <map:transform type="AboutPage"/>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the instructions you were using are out of date for DSpace 4.2. The directory structure has changed. You will need to put your file into `[dspace-src]/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/discovery/` instead.

The rest of your approach should be fine (at a cursory glance).

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while typing in the path in my question, I've put the file in `[dspace-src]/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/discovery/`. And by further studying the tutorial, I found that adding static pages in DSpace 4.2 is very simple (mentioned in point 4). A class StaticPage has already been created to serve this purpose which is mapped to  /xmlui/page/*. So one simply needs to modify the `page-structure.xsl`.

Comment: But I want to add a dynamic page to DSpace by adding a new class. How can one do that? Will the method be similar to adding a static page?

Comment: Adding a dynamic page works the same way you outlined above (with the correct path, obviously). However, this is definitely more complex than fits into the comments here on SO, so you may wish to open a new question at the very least (including a description of what you're trying to achieve with your dynamic page).